# "X" Marks the Spot

Tags: visual, knowledge

My *stupid cousin* is off on vacation somewhere. He told me he found a really nice fishing spot and if I can figure out how to get there, he'll pay for my transportation.

He sent me this map:

[image]

I'm dumbfounded. Can anyone tell me exactly where to go?

Comment: Congrats on 9000 :D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to go somewhere in the vicinity of

> Nice [EDITED: My attempts at matching the image up with a map have been a little frustrating, but Nice is in about the right place and if it's the intended answer then there's a pertinent pun up near the start of the puzzle.]

as may be more apparent if we

> change the colours of the (relief) map so that the bits denoting water are blue instead of green:
>  [image]

You can see

> the south of England at the top, Spain at the left, etc.

Comment: By definition, a nice place to go fishing.

Comment: And France, don't forget France :)

Comment: I wanted to write a negative comment but the puzzle is too nice.

Comment: Here's a [map](https://www.google.dk/maps/@34.6811429,5.2286496,1946318a,35y,3.19h,21.97t/data=!3m1!1e3) for comparison

Comment: rot13(Boivbhfyl guvf oyhr cneg urer vf gur ynaq)

Answer (score 8):

Here are some visuals to add to @Gareth's answer

> [image][image]